# Devextreme React "SassError: $color: [object Object] is not a color." error occurs

Tags: reactjs, sass, devextreme

I am using Devextreme for my React project but after the update I got this error when building..

"SassError: $color: [object Object] is not a color."

Version: 21.2.3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is when I try to build my project it changes files in themes/generated

variables.additional.scss to

```
$base-accent: [object Object];
$base-text-color: [object Object];
$base-bg: [object Object];
$base-border-color: [object Object];
$base-border-radius: [object Object];
```

and variables.base.scss file to

```
$base-accent: [object Object];
$base-text-color: [object Object];
$base-bg: [object Object];
$base-border-color: [object Object];
$base-border-radius: [object Object];
```

however if I change [object Object] to colors problem is gone..

variables.additional.scss to

```
$base-accent: #ff5722;
$base-text-color: #fff;
$base-bg: #363640;
$base-border-color: #515159;
$base-border-radius: 4px;
```

and variables.base.scss file to

```
$base-accent: #ff5722;
$base-text-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
$base-bg: #fff;
$base-border-color: #e0e0e0;
$base-border-radius: 4px;
```

Also downgrading your version will fix the problem

"devextreme-themebuilder": "20.2.6",

BTW, on some clouds, it will automatically upgrade it and changing it to the latest. In that case you simply delete some commands on your devextreme.json file.

Insted of this;

```
{
  "applicationEngine": "react",
  "build": {
      "commands": [
          {
              "command": "build-theme",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.base.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/theme.base.css"
              }
          },
          {
              "command": "build-theme",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.additional.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/theme.additional.css"
              }
          },
          {
              "command": "export-theme-vars",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.base.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/variables.base.scss"
              }
          },
          {
              "command": "export-theme-vars",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.additional.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/variables.additional.scss"
              }
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

use this;

```
{
  "applicationEngine": "react",
  "build": {
      "commands": [
          {
              "command": "build-theme",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.base.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/theme.base.css"
              }
          },
          {
              "command": "build-theme",
              "options": {
                  "inputFile": "src/themes/metadata.additional.json",
                  "outputFile": "src/themes/generated/theme.additional.css"
              }
          }
      ]
  }
}
```